# How to detect unpublished content in Joomla db?

Tags: joomla

I'll probably must create import script from Joomla.

How I can detect that selected content is not published?

I see three columns in jos_content table:

- publish_up
- publish_down
- published

I need to be sure what these columns means, to know which content is published or not.

E.g. content item:

publish_up  2008-07-09 11:17:43
publish_down    2008-10-16 00:00:00
published       2008-07-09 11:17:43

is publishes or not?

I can't check in by myself in administration panel because something is broken in the website right know, so db is the only option for me now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to look for 'state' values in the #_content table.

According to https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml, state values are:

**0** = unpublished

**1** = published

**2** = archived

**-2** = trashed / marked for deletion

You also need to check the `publish_up` and `publish_down` dates.

Comment: Thanks I ma blind, I can't accept your answer right know. I have also -2 and - 1 values, do you know what them mean?

Comment: @keram: 0 = unpublished
1 = published
-1 = Archived
-2 = marked for deletion

Comment: If `state` is `1`, can I be confident that the article is also between the `publish_up` and `publish_down` dates?

Comment: @filmm: no, you can't. You have also to check this condition before showing an article

Answer (score 5):

> 'state' values can be: -1 = archived

Not right..
**2** = archived
(Joomla 3.3.6)

Comment: I realised that the hard way..trusted on the answer above ;-), and found out now looking at the database.